# Dynamically changing positions of item locations between forms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, events, dynamic

I need some help changing the position of an item on another form dynamically.

I am trying to make a skin design tool for an app I'm making and need to know how to process an event from one form to another.

What I would like to do is set some initial variables in some text boxes and hit a preview button this will open a new form and display the skin.
Then I would like to be able to fine tune the positions of the items by clicking buttons on the 1st form.

I am ok with getting the initial positions on form2 from form1 I do it like this.

```
Form1 form1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
int xPos = 0;
int yPos = 0;
if (int.TryParse(form1.textBox1.Text, out xPos))
if (int.TryParse(form1.textBox2.Text, out yPos))
button1.Location = new Point(xPos,yPos);
```

And my button code in form1 to increase the position is this.

```
Form2 PreviewWindow = new Form2();
int newText;
int xPos = 0;
int yPos = 0;
if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out xPos))
if (int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out yPos))
PreviewWindow.button1.Location = new Point(xPos + 1 , yPos);
newText = xPos + 1;
textBox1.Text = newText.ToString();
```

But now I'm stuck on updating the event to the 2nd form.Would any of you mind giving me some pointers?

Comment: `But now im stuck on updating the event to the 2nd form. Would any of you mind giving me some pointers thanks.` I dont understand this statement what do you want to update in `Form2`

Comment: Hi i would like update the position of the button

Comment: Is it that the second code doesn't update the button location in `Form2`. In order words, the second code doesn't work as wanted?

Comment: Yes correct it does not update the position.

Comment: Check if my answer works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second code doesn't work because you're creating a new instance of `Form2`. Try this instead

```
Form2 PreviewWindow = (Form2)Application.OpenForms["Form2"];
int newText;
int xPos = 0;
int yPos = 0;
if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out xPos))
if (int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out yPos))
PreviewWindow.button1.Location = new Point(xPos + 1 , yPos);
newText = xPos + 1;
textBox1.Text = newText.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you so much that's perfect and i see my error sorry i did not explain myself very well but i am very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here will be to expose properties and/or methods in the form you wish to control.  For a `TextBox` position, for instance:

```
//Property option:
public Int32 TextBox1XPos
{
    get
    {
        return textBox1.Location.X;
    }
    set
    {
        textBox1.Location.X = value;
    }
}

public Int32 TextBox1YPos
{
    get
    {
        return textBox1.Location.Y;
    }
    set
    {
        textBox1.Location.Y = value;
    }
}

//Method option
public void MoveTextBox1(Int32 XPos, Int32 YPos)
{
    textBox1.Location = new Point(XPos, YPos);
}
```

You can implement these for any property on the form.  This gives you an indirect way of communicating with the form and doesn't require setting all controls to `Public` exposure.

Comment: Cannot modify the return value System.Windows.Forms.Control.Location because it is not a variable is what i get when looking at this.
But i totally get the concept thx